# automate volume CC of Kontakt instruments in Logic

Tags: midi, logic-pro, automation

I have a multi-instrument kontakt open in Logic, with 4 different instruments assigned to MIDI channels 1-4. Then I have 4 instrument tracks in the arrange each assigned to channels 1-4 of that instrument. A standard use of multi instrument.

Using automation such as modulation in this way is fine - each channel (1-4) can have its own modulation automation, independent of one another, which only affects the internal kontakt instrument it is routed to (as you'd expect). E.G. However, when I try to use automation on volume, for example, it affects the global kontakt channel, rather than the volume setting of the instrument within kontakt (hope this makes sense).

My question is, if I could assign a MIDI CC to the internal volume control of each kontakt instrument, I could ignore the volume CC and assign my own. This way, i could have each instrument track changing volume independently of each other (much like you can do with modulation).

How would I go about doing this? I have tried right-clicking on the volume slider, which gives me the option to assign a MIDI CC, but this requires me to move a hardware controller of some sort, and not just assign a specific channel to it.

Sorry if this isn't very clear, I hope somebody understands what I mean!

A good counter example is DP - adjusting volume of individual tracks does not affect the volume on the multi-instrument track - just the volume of the kontakt instrument that the channel is being routed to...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The way I did this was to assign a cc 11 to each volume slider in the multi (the default midi assignment is cc 7).

To do that, you open the browse pane in Kontakt, go to the Auto tab, then choose the Midi automation tab.

Now drag cc 11 onto each instruments volume slider.

If each instrument is on its own midi channel then its volume slider will respond only to a cc 11 message on that channel.  You'd need to set that up on your hardware.  i.e. set a knob or slider on your controller to transmit cc 11 on whatever midi channel you want to control.

There's a slightly fancier way to do it here that gives you a bit more control:

http://www.logicprohelp.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=30689

Comment: Some libraries that use Konkakt as their player (as well as a few of the bundled libraries I think) will respond to CC 11, meaning you don't need to map CC 11 to CC 7 within the Kontakt interface for those instruments. So try to see you your library responds to CC 11 first and you could save yourself a bit of work, although in the end the result would most likely be the same (unless the library responded differently to CC 11 than to CC 7 for some reason).